# Redefine Glossary Entry

Tags: glossaries

How can I redefine a glossary record, I am writing a custom class, and want to define some 'default' glossary terms as part of the class, however, may wish to redefine them at the document-level on a case-by-case basis.

At the moment, If I try to define a glossary record that already exists, it throws an already defined error, this is relating to the `Glossaries` package.

Here is an example, in this, a glossary record is created in the trivial class definition, as a default instance. As it stands, this compiles fine, however, if the attempted redefinition in the actual document is un-commented, the error is produced, reporting that the glossary record already exists.

```
%===================================================
%A Trivial Class
%===================================================
\begin{filecontents*}{democlass_v3.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{democlass_v3}[6/6/2013 democlass]
    \LoadClassWithOptions{article}

    \RequirePackage{glossaries}

    %<<<<<< FIRST DEFINITION >>>>>>%
    \newglossaryentry{pg}{   
        name={pg.},
        description={Short Page Abbreviation},
        first={pg.},
        firstplural={pp.},
        plural={pp.}
    }
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass{democlass_v3}

%===================================================
%BELOW REDEFINITION THROWS ERROR IF UNCOMMENTED...
%===================================================
%<<<<<< ATTEMPTED REDEFINITION >>>>>>%
%\newglossaryentry{pg}{
%   name={page},
%   description={Short Page Abbreviation - Redefined},
%   first={page},
%   firstplural={pages},
%   plural={pages}
%}
%===================================================

\begin{document}

The page glossary record is: \gls{pg}

\end{document}
```

The specific Error thrown is:

`Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry 'pg' has already been defined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that you really want to do this. However, here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% This will go in the class file
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newcommand{\renewglossaryentry}[1]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{#1}
   {\global\csundef{glo@#1@name}}
   {}
   \newglossaryentry{#1}
}

\newglossaryentry{pg}{   
   name={pg.},
   description={Short Page Abbreviation},
   first={pg.},
   firstplural={pp.},
   plural={pp.}
}
%%% End of code in the class file

\makeglossaries

\renewglossaryentry{pg}{
   name={page},
   description={Short Page Abbreviation - Redefined},
   first={page},
   firstplural={pages},
   plural={pages}
}

\begin{document}

The page glossary record is: \gls{pg}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

As long as the glossary entry is not used before redefinition, all should go well.

[image]

Comment: That's it. I'll relax the `renewglossaryentry{...}` command at the beginning of the document, via `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\renewglossaryentry\relax}` in the custom class, that way, it can only be used in preamble.

Comment: @ADP Say `\@onlypreamble\renewglossaryentry` in the class file, which is the standard method for disabling commands after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Well f me dead, you learn something new every day. Cheers.